# Simple SQL code keeps returning echo 0. No idea how to fix it

Tags: php, sql

Is there something syntactically wrong with my code here? It always seems to echo 0?

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_NUM)){
        if ($row[7] !=false){
            $Tprice = $Tprice + ($row[3] * $row[7]);
        }
    }
    echo $Tprice;

    ?>
```

I'm at a complete loss... Thanks!

Comment: what is the value of $row[7]?

Comment: If you have done any syntax error, It would not be run without an error. Now you have a comparable code means , the error with your logic. Please post your query and table for better understanding.

Comment: row7 is quantity, row3 is price

Comment: Add `echo $Tprice`, after `$Tprice = $Tprice + ($row[3] * $row[7]);`. See what it is returning.